# \leaders in redefining \headrule cause "A <box> was supposed to be here"

Tags: boxes, fancyhdr

After stripping away hundreds of line of code to reach this MWE, I found that my "A «box» was supposed to be here" seemed to be caused by a `\renewcommand{\headrule}` in conjunction with `fancyhdr`.

Moreover, the error goes away if I delete `\leaders` from the `\box` specification.

This redefinition was something that I cobbled together at some point, undoubtedly inspired by examples I didn't fully understand.

I'd appreciate insight into why I'm getting this error and how to rewrite it to squash that error.

```
\documentclass[12pt,final]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
        \hbox to\headwidth{\leaders\rule[5pt]{\headwidth}{0.4pt}\hfill}%
%       \hbox to\headwidth{\rule[5pt]{\headwidth}{0.4pt}\hfill}%
    }%
\begin{document}
Hello, world.
\end{document}
```

P.S., the error message isn't really "«box»" but rather the « and » should be replaced with less-than and greater-than signs. Those were rejected when I entered them here.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? That would be a better question. A header rule? A special header rule? Please enlighten us.

Comment: @Werner, I currently have, and like: a headrule and a footrule, each spanning exactly the width of the text. I use the optional argument of `\rule` to fine-tune the vertical position of each rule. I also set a color for these rules (though I removed that from the MWE because it wasn't causing trouble).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the rule is set in vertical mode and that's where you're running into problems with your `\hbox to \headwidth` (which is similar to `\makebox[\headwidth]`) approach.

This is what [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)'s `\headrule` looks like (using `\show\headrule`):

```
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
    \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth
    \vskip-\headrulewidth}}
```

Apart from the condition an `\hrule` is inserted and the rule thickness is underdone (vertically). I would just replicate the behaviour using something like

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
  \vskip -5pt % Move head rule up by 5pt
  \hrule \@height 0.4pt \@width \headwidth % Place head rule
  \vskip \dimexpr-0.4pt + 5pt\relax % Remove space inserted by raise and rule
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: That does the trick! I shouldn't have left my \color{blue} out of my MWE. I'm not sure where to put that in the context of your solution?

Comment: @JimRatliff: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/nMRGMRXh). The group doesn't seem to be necessary here, but it's always good to limit the scope of something that might have a broader impact (like `\color`, here).